# How to run a local server/client application?

Tags: tomcat, client-server

We want to transform a java application to a client/server form , but we want it to run on the local machine (in the future it will support remote servers).

Is there a way to start tomcat/IIS with the application itself and be done? Or do I need to deploy the application into the tomcat/IIS and then access the url? 
Can I just add some tomcat jar to my application and make it a webserver too?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.

- [How to install Tomcat](http://www.javabeat.net/tips/119-how-to-install-tomcat-60-server.html)
- [How to install Tomcat + How to deploy web-app](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/deployer-howto.html)

Comment: Description images in first link are all missing